# typescript 2.8 Exclude: possible to supercharge the 'partition' type?

Tags: typescript

I would like to improve the type of [the partition function](http://emmanueltouzery.github.io/prelude.ts/latest/apidoc/classes/vector.html#partition) in my TS library.

Applying it to `Array`, the type is:

```
function partition<T>(list: T[], predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [T[],T[]];
```

And an example of invocation would be:

```
[1,2,3,4].partition(x => x%2===0)
=> [[2,4],[1,3]]
```

Now typescript 2.8 adds [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21847), and in particular [Exclude](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1371) (note that typescript 2.8 is only in release candidate stage at this point).

So my idea to improve the type of partition, so it's possible to take advantage of type guards, would be something like that:

```
function partition<T>(list: T[], predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [T[],T[]];
function partition<T,U extends T>(list: T[], predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [U[],Array<Exclude<T,U>>];
```

Unfortunately I can't get this to compile with `--strict` with typescript 2.8rc.

Here is a sample program:

```
function partition<T>(list: T[], predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [T[],T[]];
function partition<T,U extends T>(list: T[], predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [U[],Array<Exclude<T,U>>];
function partition<T,U extends T>(list: T[], predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [U[],Array<Exclude<T,U>>] {
    return <any>[];
}
```

Compile with TS 2.8rc with `--strict` to reproduce the build error, which is:

```
test.ts(2,10): error TS2394: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.
```

Looking at the definition of `Exclude`, I've also attempted to change the other definition to return, instead of `[T[],T[]]`, rather `[T[], Array<T|never>>]`, but that didn't help, I still get the same error.

Is it possible to achieve what I want with typescript 2.8?

**UPDATE** Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer does make that work but that was on the reduced test-case, it still doesn't work for me in a class:

```
class Vector<T> {
    partition<U extends T>(predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [Vector<U>,Vector<Exclude<T, U>>];
    partition(predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [Vector<T>,Vector<T>];
    partition<U extends T>(predicate:(v:T)=>boolean):  [Vector<U>,Vector<Exclude<T, U>>] {
        return <any>[];
    }
}
```

Apparently doing it in a class triggers extra checks or something like that, because that's the same code that works outside of a class...

This works:

```
class Vector<T> {}

function partition<T,U extends T>(list: Vector<T>, predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [Vector<U>,Vector<Exclude<T, U>>];
function partition<T>(list: Vector<T>, predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [Vector<T>,Vector<T>];
function partition<T,U extends T>(list: Vector<T>, predicate:(v:T)=>boolean):  [Vector<U>,Vector<Exclude<T, U>>] {
    return <any>[];
}
```

But just putting the code in the class breaks it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation signature needs to be a bit more inclusive, the predicate can't be a type guard, since in some overloads it is not a type guard. Also the order of overloads needs to be different, as the first one will catch any case that the second one will, signatures are considered in declaration order.

```
function partition<T,U extends T>(list: T[], predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [U[],Array<Exclude<T, U>>];
function partition<T>(list: T[], predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [T[],T[]];
function partition<T,U extends T>(list: T[], predicate:(v:T)=>boolean):  [U[],Array<Exclude<T, U>>] {
    return <any>[];
}
// Usage
declare let arr: (string| number)[];

function isNumber(n: string| number) : n is number {
    return typeof n === 'number';
}

let k = partition(arr, isNumber) // will be [number[], string[]]
```

For the Vector example, the signature can use `Vector<any>` that will be compatible with both `Vector<T>` and `Vector<Exclude<T, U>>`. Not sure why it is allowed in the first example but not in this one.

```
class Vector<T> {
    partition<U extends T>(predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [Vector<U>,Vector<Exclude<T, U>>];
    partition(predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [Vector<T>,Vector<T>];
    partition<U extends T>(predicate:(v:T)=>boolean):  [Vector<U>,Vector<any>] {
        return <any>[];
    }
}

declare var v: Vector<string| number>;
function isNumber(n: string| number) : n is number {
    return typeof n === 'number';
}
var d = v.partition(isNumber) // will be  [Vector<number>, Vector<string>]
```

Comment: Ok that was very interesting, thank you! I didn't realize the implementation signature could be different from either overload. However I'm still stuck because I was doing that inside of a class. I have updated the question, inside of a class I'm still getting the issue :-(

Comment: thank you! interestingly in emacs I see `Vector<any>` for the type of d[1] in your example but this appears to be a weakness of emacs type integration since the compiler sees the true type and `const e: Vector<string> = d[1]` does compile. Thank you!