# type A is not assignable to type B with typescript 2.8 conditional types

Tags: typescript

this is actually a followup on [typescript 2.8 Exclude: possible to supercharge the 'partition' type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463733/typescript-2-8-exclude-possible-to-supercharge-the-partition-type) -- I'm having issues introducing conditional types in my code.

Note that conditional types are new with typescript 2.8, so currently this must be built with typescript 2.8rc.

I've reduced my current issue to this pretty small test case:

```
export class Option<T> {
    toVector(): Vector<T> {
        return <any>undefined;
    }
}

interface Seq<T> {
    tail(): Option<Seq<T>>;
}

class Vector<T> implements Seq<T> {

    tail(): Option<Vector<T>> {
        return <any>undefined;
    }

     // the next line breaks the compilation
    partition2<U extends T>(predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [Vector<U>,Vector<Exclude<T,U>>];
    partition2(predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [Vector<T>,Vector<T>];
    partition2<U extends T>(predicate:(v:T)=>boolean): [Vector<U>,Vector<any>] {
        return <any>undefined;
    }
}
```

The new line is the first overload for `partition2`. If you comment it, all builds fine.

If you compile this with `--strict`, it fails with a rather baffling build error:

```
t.ts(13,5): error TS2416: Property 'tail' in type 'Vector<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Seq<T>'.
  Type '() => Option<Vector<T>>' is not assignable to type '() => Option<Seq<T>>'.
    Type 'Option<Vector<T>>' is not assignable to type 'Option<Seq<T>>'.
      Types of property 'toVector' are incompatible.
        Type '() => Vector<Vector<T>>' is not assignable to type '() => Vector<Seq<T>>'.
          Type 'Vector<Vector<T>>' is not assignable to type 'Vector<Seq<T>>'.
            Types of property 'tail' are incompatible.
              Type '() => Option<Vector<Vector<T>>>' is not assignable to type '() => Option<Vector<Seq<T>>>'.
                Type 'Option<Vector<Vector<T>>>' is not assignable to type 'Option<Vector<Seq<T>>>'.
                  Types of property 'toVector' are incompatible.
                    Type '() => Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>' is not assignable to type '() => Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>'.
                      Type 'Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>' is not assignable to type 'Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>'.
                        Types of property 'tail' are incompatible.
                          Type '() => Option<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>' is not assignable to type '() => Option<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>'.
                            Type 'Option<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>' is not assignable to type 'Option<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>'.
                              Types of property 'toVector' are incompatible.
                                Type '() => Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>' is not assignable to type '() => Vector<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>'.
                                  Type 'Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>' is not assignable to type 'Vector<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>'.
                                    Types of property 'tail' are incompatible.
                                      Type '() => Option<Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>>' is not assignable to type '() => Option<Vector<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>>'.
                                        Type 'Option<Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>>' is not assignable to type 'Option<Vector<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>>'.
                                          Types of property 'toVector' are incompatible.
                                            Type '() => Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>>' is not assignable to type '() => Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>>'.
                                              Type 'Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>>' is not assignable to type 'Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>>'.
                                                Type 'Vector<Vector<Vector<Seq<T>>>>' is not assignable to type 'Vector<Vector<Vector<Vector<T>>>>'.
```

I don't really know what to do to make this work :-(

Comment: Gotta love typescript errors...

Comment: so, tail is supposed to return an `Option<Seq<T>>`, but since `Option.toVector()` returns `Vector<T>` this means `tail().toVector()` returns `Vector<Vector<T>>` is this your intent ? Because it looks like the erorr

Comment: as you can imagine, Option is Some (value present) or None (no value). Some(6).toVector=>Vector.of(6). None().toVector()=>Vector.empty(). So yes... Vector.of(5,6,7).tail()=>Option.of(Vector.of(6,7)). Vector.of(5,6,7).tail().toVector() => Vector.of(Vector.of(6,7))

Comment: Wow, this feels like a bug or design limitation.  You might want to file an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) about it (although I wish there were a smaller repro).

Comment: Edited your question to add in what I think is a smaller repro.  Also commented on your [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22860)

Comment: @jcalz as I mentioned feel free to write an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Okay, done.  Thanks to @TitianCernicova-Dragomir for your help with this also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, this looks like a compiler bug (or at least a design limitation).  The minimal reproduction I can find looks like this:

```
interface A<T> {
    bat: B<A<T>>;
}

interface B<T> extends A<T> {
    bat: B<B<T>>;
    boom: true
}
```

Everything's okay here.  All the type parameters are in [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Generic_types) positions, which means that if `Y` is a subtype of `X`, then `A<Y>` is a subtype of `A<X>`, and `B<Y>` is a subtype of `B<X>`.  And since `B<T>` is a subtype of `A<T>`, you can deduce that, specifically, `B<B<T>>` is a subtype of `B<A<T>>`.  Therefore it is fine that the `bat` property of `B` narrows `B<A<T>>` to `B<B<T>>`.

---

Now watch what happens when we add a conditional type (that doesn't get immediately evaluated) to `B`:

```
interface A<T> {
    bat: B<A<T>>;
}
interface B<T> extends A<T> {
//        ^ error
// Interface 'B<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'A<T>'.
    bat: B<B<T>>;

    boom: T extends any ? true : true
}
```

It explodes.  `boom` will undoubtedly still be of type `true`, but somehow the deferred conditional type is causing trouble.  From the error, it's clear that the compiler is chasing down whether `B<T>` is compatible with `A<T>` by checking whether `B<B<T>>` is compatible with `B<A<T>>` by checking whether `B<B<B<T>>>` is compatible with `B<B<A<T>>>` by... uh oh.

So there's some kind of infinite regress in the type checker which bails out early... that's good, since otherwise the compiler would just hang.  But when it bails out it decides that `B<T>` is *not* compatible with `A<T>`, which is bad for us (although a rule like "bail out with success" is probably bad too).

---

So, my suggestion is to do what you did and [file the issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22860).  We'll see what they say about it there.

I'm not sure if there are any really easy workarounds.  I'll edit this answer if I find one.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Seq<T>.tail` returns `Option<Seq<T>>` while `Vector<T>.tail` returns `Option<Vector<T>>`. These two types are not compatible, as the compiler to verbosely tells us. The simplest solution, is to change `Seq<T>` to return an `Option` of the same type as the current type, whatever that type may be. This means that the implementation of `tail` in `Vector<T>` will return `Option<Vector<T>>` as expected, but will be compatible with the definition of `tail` in `Seq`. We can do this using the `this` type:

```
export class Option<T> {
    toVector(): Vector<T> {
        return <any>undefined;
    }
}

interface Seq<T> {
    tail(): Option<this>;
}

class Vector<T> implements Seq<T> {

    tail(): Option<this> {
        return <any>undefined;
    }

    // the next line breaks the compilation
    partition2<U extends T>(predicate:(v:T)=>v is U): [Vector<U>,Vector<Exclude<T,U>>];
    partition2(predicate:(x:T)=>boolean): [Vector<T>,Vector<T>];
    partition2<U extends T>(predicate:(v:T)=>boolean): [Vector<U>,Vector<any>] {
        return <any>undefined;
    }
}

declare var v: Vector<number>;
var d = v.tail().toVector() // will be Vector<Vector<number>>
```

Comment: right, I was suspecting for quite some time that I should not be doing inheritance/implements like that.. but it did compile :( `this` works nice in this case but what if I want to implement `map`? Then I must return `Seq<U>` in Seq and `Vector<U>` in Vector... even worse if I want to (and I want to) put `partition2` in Seq... Is that even possible then?

Comment: But *why* is `Option<Vector<T>>` not compatible with `Option<Seq<T>>`?  `Option<X>` is covariant in `X` so `Option<Y>` should be a subtype of `Option<X>` whenever `Y` is a subtype of `X`.  And `Vector<T>` is definitely a subtype of`Seq<T>`.

Comment: to be clear: `map<U>(mapper:(v:T)=>U): Seq<U>;` in Seq and then `map<U>(fun:(x:T)=>U): Vector<U>` in Vector.

Comment: @jcalz I tried to track that down … not sure why yet.. but I wouldn't jump to compiler bug just yet ..

Comment: The conditional type is definitely causing something weird to happen in the type checker.  The type checker seems to be trying to *verify* that `Vector<T>` is assignable to `Seq<T>`, chasing down an infinite regress, bailing out, and failing.  If that's not some kind of bug (or at least a design limitation) I'd be surprised.

Comment: @jcalz Yup, I was just about to write that .. it just keeps going and eventually gives up ..

Comment: Even in your "fixed" code with `this`, I get an error here: `const seq : Seq<number> = new Vector<number>();` which really shouldn't happen given `Vector<T> implements Seq<T>`.

Comment: @jcalz Hm, did not notice that .. you are right it seems like a bug .. you should be able to do that assignment by definition ..

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery just a suggestion … maybe have a `toSeq(): Seq<T>` instead ? That seems to work.. and file the bug for the compiler :)

Comment: Ok I'll file the bug. For the suggestion.. I don't want to break the API of my library, plus I've reduced the issue to that testcase but it feels like it's half my library which doesn't build anymore. There have got to be more of these cases all over. The output of `tsc | wc -l` is 1168 lines long on my real-world project =D

Comment: I have filed https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22860 -- thanks for the help!

Comment: To award the answer to someone, since I can't give it to both, maybe @jcalz since you suggested it's a bug and came up with the "const seq" assignment, if you want you could write an answer that it's most likely a bug and I should report it, I can mark it as the answer. But thanks to both! I didn't rule out your toSeq "workaround" by the way Titian Cernicova-Dragomir. But my first hope is that an updated compiler makes this work as-is.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery I'd up vote jcalz's answer too if he posted one, he was right it was a bug :-)